# I short circuited my iPhone 5 through audio jack

Tags: hardware

Long story short, I short circuited my second most expensive asset through a [usb-male-audio-male](http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/1765417403_1/For-iPod-Shuffle-Cable-USB-Charger-SYNC-M-to-M-3-5mm-Audio-Headphone-Jack-12cm.jpg). I'm devastated. I'm not rich. I was still giddy about saving a dozen dollars during black friday sales.

I understand basic elements of circuits. So I want to fix it myself.

I suspect that the battery is down. And I suspect some excessive current protection mechanism was triggered. 
[The battery can be replaced easily.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00T8WER1O)

So my question is that what might have been broken, and how to fix them.

If you can kindly share your knowledge, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

a reset solved the problem

> Try a reset, press the top and and home button at the same time

I found this [solution by sarri at fixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/97121/Short+circuit+REALLY+need+help!)